# How does windows really choose the right image from a resource?

Tags: windows, winapi, colors, icons

I read [the following on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997538.aspx):

> Once an RT_GROUP_ICON is chosen, the individual icon image, or RT_ICON resource, must be selected and extracted. Again, if there exists only one RT_ICON resource for the group in question, the choice is trivial. However, if multiple images are present in the group, the following selection rules are applied:
>
> 1. The image closest in size to the
>    requested size is chosen.
> 2. If two or more images of that size are present, the one that matches the color depth of the display is chosen.
> 3. If none exactly match the color depth of the display, Windows chooses the image with the greatest color depth without exceeding the color depth of the display.
> 4. If all the size-matched images exceed the color depth of the display, the one with the lowest color depth is chosen.
> 5. Windows treats all color depths of 8 or more bpp as equal. For example, it is pointless to have a 16x16 256 color image and a 16x16 16bpp image in the same resource—Windows will simply choose the first one it encounters.
> 6. When the display is in 8bpp mode, Windows will prefer a 16 color icon over a 256 color icon, and will display all icons using the system default palette.

But I [also read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997538.aspx) that developers should provide an 8-bit and 24-bit, 8-bit and 4-bit versions of each size to support different depths. If #5 above is true, why do I need the 8-bit version? And if #5 is true, how does #6 apply?

How does Windows really choose? Does it really matter to include all these color depths if windows treats them all the same?

Comment: Your link dates from the stone age, 16 years is a very long time ago.  The odds that you'll run into a video adapter that runs at 8bpp are zero.

Comment: @Hans - Current documentation states the same though: [About Icons # Icon Display](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648050%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_win32_Icon_Display). 1,2,3,4 is in list items of *(2)*, 5, 6 is in the *note*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If #5 is true, the order of icons is important:

- 32x32x16bpp << Will be chosen if display is >= 16bpp
- 32x32x8bpp << Will be chosen if display is < 16bpp and could be designed to look better than a auto converted true color icon

(I know the icon editor I use automatically sorts the icons by size and color depth when you save)

If your app runs on < XP it is also important to provide icons < 32bpp since Win9x/2000 has problems with the alpha transparency.

I'm pretty sure #6 is not true, IIRC the plus pack for Win95 enabled the shell to use 256 colors over the default 16 color icons.

Vista added [LoadIconMetric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775701%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and it tries to scale icons down with a better source icon algorythm.

Most people run @ 32bpp these days so the color depth and 16/256 color icons is probably not that important anymore...

Comment: ... of course, if there's a chance your icon will show up in safe mode, a 16-color version might actually be a pretty good idea.